# Conditionally Importing header files in Universal ios app

Tags: iphone, objective-c

in my Universal ios app I have two header files like `FrameRates_iPad.h` and `FrameRates_iPhone.h` which I need to import into viewcontroller class depending on the current device the app is building for, please help me in achieving this.

Answer (score 0):

I like to use 1 controller for my universal apps. There’s no need to use `FrameRates_iPad.h` and `FrameRates_iPhone.h` and write the same code twice! Here is how I use 1 controller for both iPad and iPhone specific code.

You can check out [my post on how I use Macros](http://code.wrightscs.com/?p=56).

One way to check what device you are running code on is to use `UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM()`. The `UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM` returns the interface idiom supported by the current device and is available in iOS 3.2 +.

```
#define IDIOM    UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM()
#define IPAD     UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad   /* iPad, obviously               */
#define IPHONE   UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone /* iPhone, to include iPod touch */
```

### Example of using the interface idiom to determine what code to run:

This code says that if the device is an iPad, then it can autorotate, otherwise, if the device is an iPhone or equivalent, the only orientation supported will be Portrait.

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    if ( IDIOM == IPAD ) {
        return YES;
    }else{
        return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
    }
    return YES;
}
```

### Another example on when to use this:

Set a specific size for a button, or any other object that has a frame property.

```
CGRect frame;
if ( IDIOM == IPAD ) {
    frame = CGRectMake(tableView.frame.size.width-105,5,30,30);
} else {
    frame = CGRectMake(tableView.frame.size.width-60,5,30,30);
}

UIButton *aButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame: frame ];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set preprocessor macro **IS_IPAD = 1** for your **iPad_target** in xcode build settings and then:

```
#ifdef IS_IPAD
#import "FrameRates_iPad.h"
#endif

#ifndef IS_IPAD
#import "FrameRates_iPhone.h"
#endif
```